# Сохранение порядка при добавление элемента во множество HashSet Java

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста , как сохранить порядок тот в котором были добавлены элементы в множество в Java . Допустим если добавлять по 1 элементу , то оно их раскидывает в произвольном порядке.

```
HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();
    int i = 5;
    while (i>0) {
        try { 
            hs.add(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter set element"));
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Something wrong", "Error",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        i--;
    }
Подскажите как сделать чтобы сохранялся порядок ввода ?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).